# How to troubleshoot stunnel dropping repeatedly?

Tags: windows, stunnel

I don't know much about stunnel but we use it in many locations to connect from a Java app to a cloud database. We have one Windows computer where stunnel keeps dying. What might cause this? How can I troubleshoot it?